# Getting history.js to work without Ajax loaded pages

Tags: jquery, history.js

I don't know why this isn't working and I've been trying everything.

Most of the tutorials online are using Ajax which I'm not and I've tried adapting it but I can't get anything to work. I'm using has bang urls and all the content is loaded in the index page it's just being shown and hidden dynamically. I could really use some help getting the history working.

Here is my script...

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', handleStateChange);
$('nav a').on('click',function(e) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    History.pushState(null, null, target);
});

function handleStateChange() {
    alert("State changed...");
}
```

If I could just get the alert to happen I can go from there but the alert never fires and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define your function before binding the event, in this way:

```
function handleStateChange() {
    alert("State changed...");
}
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', handleStateChange);
$('nav a').on('click',function(e) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    History.pushState(null, null, target);
});
```

Or much better as I like usually to do, define the function inside the bind, of course if you don't need to use the same function later in the script.

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
    alert("State changed...");
});

$('nav a').on('click',function(e) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    History.pushState(null, null, target);
});
```

Comment: Hi MacK, I have a question similar it. If I use it in one page such as: a.html?state=1 and a.html?state=2, the script will work fine. However, I use History.js in two pages such as: a.html and b.html. So, it can not run. Please help me in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586033/how-to-use-history-js-to-capture-back-event

Answer (score 1):

i think that "$('nav a')" is a typo in the code you have posted, it should be:

```
....
$('#nav a').on('click',function(e) {
var target = $(this).attr('href');
....
```

In this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lollo/Su7wy/1/) i assume that you want use a tag div with "nav" as id attribute and some links inside of it
Hope it helps..

Comment: The _[nav](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nav)_ element is a new HTML5 tag, not really a typo in this case :)

Comment: i didn't know about that new tag... so if you treat it like  'div' or 'p' or like any other tag i assume that : $('nav').find('a') is the right way to code it...